# How to apply custom analyzers on a field in Vespa schema

Tags: search, vespa

I have the following schema

```
schema product {
    document product {
        field brand_name type string {
            indexing: summary | index
        }
        field brand_name_tokens type array<string> {    #computed field
            ....
        }
}
```

I want to have a field called `brand_name_tokens` of type `array<string>` in the document which is derived from `brand_name` field as follows

- split `brand_name` by white space and then remove substring `[™®]` if present.

I can do this processing before writing to Vespa. I would like to know if its possible to define this in the schema so that Vespa automatically computes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this - there's a "split by regex". There's no "remove substring" but if you don't mind splitting on ™/® then you can do it with a slightly fancier regex.

It looks a little different because you can't input unicode characters directly in the schema so you have to replace ™ with `\xe2\x84\xa2`:

```
field brand_name_tokens type array<string> {
    indexing: input brand_name | split "([. ®]|\xe2\x84\xa2)+" | summary
}
```

As this is a computed field, it should be defined outside the `document product {` block.

See https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/indexing-language-reference.html#split and the rest of the page for what you can do at indexing time. If you need to do more, you can write a custom Document Processor